# Android Filter class performFiltering method

Tags: java, android, web, filter, android-asynctask

In my android application i integrated custom Filter class to filter data that comes from server.

Here is some explanations,

```
private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
    Filter.FilterResults results = new Filter.FilterResults();

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {

       ....
        // Here i need to call web service and need to fetch data from server.
        // I need to return this method when i get response from server only
        // So logically i do not need to call this return results method until server respond
       ......

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            ........
            ........


    }
}
```

**- How should i able to return that method only when i get response from server?**

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Unable to to comment but is there a specific reason the filter is downloading the data instead of a service, fragment or even adapter? To keep it in the same class maybe create a downloading thread within the adapter that is wrapping the filter. When the thread returns and calls adapter.reset, add, etc. Youd then call the getfilter().filter method.